# About jquery .css method

Tags: jquery, css

I can't make this script to work. I searched online and I can't find any good answer.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#container").click(function(){
    var color = $(this).css("background");
    if(color == "#ffffff"){
        $(this).css("background", "#e1e1e1");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background", "#ffffff");
    }

});

});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Document sans nom</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <a href="#" class="a">Start</a>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you also share your HTML or recreate your page on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.css('background')` may not return the color in the format you assume it is returning, based on browser it may return a hexa, rgb or rgba format

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#container").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", function () {
            var color = $(this).data("background") == '#e1e1e1' ? '#ffffff' : '#e1e1e1';
            $(this).data('background', color);
            return color;
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qh4T4/)

---

But a far more easier solution is to use toggleClass() like

```
#container {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#container.toggled {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#container").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4sG3M/)

Comment: @David if this answers your question, you should accept this answer as the correct one, by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.css("background-color");` but this will return as a rgb not hex so you would need to modify your code slightly.

Hope this helps